# Calling SharePoint web services

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

After some research on calling SharePoint webservices, it seems that using the following URL:

```
https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl
```

would allow me to request data from SharePoint sites that I have access to.

If that URL doesn't return anything (404), does that mean that the webservices have been disabled by the Admin (Enterprise context)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it return 404 error? it means not found.

Comment: Does that mean it has been disabled by the admin? Shouldn't all the sharepoint sites have the wsdl associated with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 Mean file not found.

Couple of things to check and correct.

- Make sure the Address is correct...try to browse the site collection without `/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl` and see if you get the site. For my guess you site collection address is not correct...isn't http://www.something.com/sites/url?
- also remove the wsdl at the end then try
  -

Comment: It works fine without wsdl. Isn't the wsdl necessary to query my site though?

Comment: check this for the anwser...same issue..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226873/how-do-i-access-the-service-definition-for-a-specific-sharepoint-list-web-servic